# jQuery: Wrapping a part of text with a span

Tags: jquery, regex

How would I go about wrapping a section of text in a paragraph with a span. For instance, in:

```
<p class="info"> Posted by johnny, 20/07/2012 4:47pm (3 days ago) </p>
```

I would like to be able to wrap the poster's name with a span, this is not necessarily always going to be 1 word, it could be John Smith, or John H Smith.

Basically I want to wrap whatever comes after "Posted by" and before the last comma (,) in the paragraph.

I would assume regex is the way forward but I've never touched this before.

Comment: Are you open to doing this server side instead? it will be MUCH easier and more efficient

Comment: @Sam +1 This should definitely be done server side, if at all possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.info').html(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(/(Posted by )([^,]+)(,)/, '$1<span class="auther">$2</span>$3');
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Urph/

Comment: This is really useful but I am wondering could anyone explain to me why the i argument is needed in the function please?

Answer (score 1):

> I would assume regex is the way forward but I've never touched this before.

Not necessarily, though it's one option.

Basically, you have to find the comma (because you already know how long `"Posted by"` is). The easiest way to find it is `String#indexOf`. Having found it, you just need to split the text. You can do that like this: [Live example](http://jsbin.com/orepow) | [source](http://jsbin.com/orepow/edit)

```
$("p.info").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        html = $this.html(),
        comma = html.indexOf(",");
    html = html.substring(0, 10) + // 10 = length of "Posted by "
           "<span>" +
           html.substring(10, comma) +
           "</span>" +
           html.substring(comma);
    $this.html(html);
});
```

...or alternately you can do much the same thing with the DOM API's [`splitText` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-38853C1D).

Comment: Great solution. It did the trick, however I went with Joseph's solution in the end. Thank you though.